# Activation lock kicking in after months

Tags: activation-lock

I'm a developer and I bought a 2nd hand iPad for development aid in June 2019.

It came with the usual Hello setup screen, so I put my email and password and evertything was fine.

I was able to use iCloud, was able to debug my app on it, everything was normal.

In app purchases was difficult to test because my developer accounts grants me free subscriptions on my own apps, so I created another iCloud account and used on this iPad (and also on an iPhone 5 I have for the same purpose). Again, everything worked fine.

Last week, the iPad updated itself to iOS 12.4.6 and, after that I have used the reset function to clear it (I wanted a clean first use experience for some new developments I'm testing).

Now it keeps telling me this device is locked and asking for an e-mail/password that is not mine (as it masks the e-mail, I can't even tell who owns it).

So, what happened? This iPad was stolen before I bought and I just have luck setupping in the first place?

The iPhone Finder doesn't show it on my account (although it appears on my iCloud devices list, but the only action I can do here is to forget it)

I'm having trouble understanding if this is a mistake or anything else (if I never could pass the activation, ok, I could do something when I bought it, but the activation kicking in just now is insane!)

[image]

Comment: I see that you mentioned that you were unable to use your Apple ID to unlock the iPad. Have you tried the passcode option? Also, you can try removing the device from your Apple ID to eliminate activation lock from your Apple ID if that was the case and your ID wasn’t working for some reason.

Comment: Problem is: the activation lock is NOT for my AppleID. I supose is from the original user (but as Apple masks the e-mail address, I can't e-mail him to know if he/she really sold the iPad or if it is stolen (since I apparently bought from a 3rd party) =\

Comment: I am aware that there is no such thing as Activation Lock for Apple ID. I said, since you can see the iPad in Find My, you should remove it which might also remove Activation Lock on the iPad.

Comment: Sorry, this screenshot is not from Find My iPhone. It's from iCloud Account devices list. When I click remove, the only thing it does is take this device out of my devices list (it doesn't erase nor forbids me to keep using my Apple Id on that device). Basically, is useless in this case. I just tested now with my iPhone and nothing happened (interest fact: on the iPhone, the lost iPad is listed with Find My iPad as inactive)

Comment: Try a reinstall of iOS/iPadOS. To do this, get your iPad into Recovery Mode. Then, in iTunes on your Mac or PC, click Update. If you would like to erase all data, you can try Restore.

Comment: Tried that (including reverting the iOS version to the previous version).

Comment: At this point, you should contact the previous owner and have them verify that it isn't under their Apple ID anymore. Please refer to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365.